# .NET / Dapper / Oracle - Query works for one table, but returns nothing for another

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, dapper

### Context

I have two tables, `FOO` and `BAR`. Both have data. I'm using Dapper in a .NET 5 project. When I try to query `FOO`, I get zero results. When I query `BAR` with the same connection, I get results as expected. What's going on?

### Example code

```
using var connection = GetConnection();
await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);

// THIS RETURNS ZERO RESULTS
var foos = await connection.QueryAsync("SELECT * FROM FOO");

// THIS RETURNS RESULTS AS EXPECTED
var bars = await connection.QueryAsync("SELECT * FROM BAR");

// THIS THROWS AN EXCEPTION (because the table doesn't exist)
var throws = await connection.QueryAsync("SELECT * FROM DOES_NOT_EXIST");
```

### Other thoughts

- I've confirmed my connection string is correct
- I've confirmed `FOO` exists in the DB defined by my connection string
- I've confirmed `FOO` has data
- I've confirmed I can query `FOO` successfully via Oracle SQL Developer
- `FOO` is a new table created in the past couple days

Does anybody know what's happening here?

Or what might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anybody know what's happening here?

Rows which have been `INSERT`ed but not `COMMIT`ted are only visible inside the session in which they were created. Therefore, if you have created some new rows but have not issued a `COMMIT` command in the SQL Developer session, you will not be able to see that uncommitted data from any other session (even if you connect as the same user, as it will create a different session).

If this is the the case, the solution would be to `COMMIT` the data in the SQL Developer session and it would then be visible to other sessions.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I figured it was something basic related to Oracle specifics.

Comment: Thanks folks. arrgh, I always miss this caveat and lose time. I bite now, and changed the `Preferences` > `Database` > `Advanced` > `Autocommit` setting to true.

-> [Link to Settings walkthrough](https://www.databasestar.com/sql-developer-autocommit/) Good luck!